# jquery functions within Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, function, fancybox

I'm using fancybox to load up some inline content on a web page.

Fancybox loads up fine as do the images, the only problem is that I would like certain jquery functions to work within the modal window which will not load up.

The jquery functions work fine when I load them outside of fancybox so was wondering if anyone knows how to call these functions when the window is open?

**EDIT**

so i have tried the callbackonshow but cannot get it to work, what am i doing wrong here?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function hover() {
    $("#container ul#thumbnails li a").hover(
        function(){

      var largePath = $(this).attr("name");

      $("#container #main_image img#largeId").attr({ src: largePath }); return false);
    }

    $("a.group").fancybox({
              'frameWidth': 966,
              'frameHeight': 547,
              'hideOnContentClick': false,
              'callbackOnShow': hover
              });

   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to use the callbackOnShow option to pass in a function.

It's outlined here: [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/howto)

[Brandon Joyce](http://blog.sonerdy.com)

Comment: that seems to be the right direction but i cannot get me function to load - see above if you can help!

Comment: try just replacing hover with function() { alert("test"); }

That will tell you if it's executing it or not.